# SparkSQL DataFrame: sql query does not work when using caching

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm starting to use spark for my learning. I made a simple program based on [this document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/sql-programming-guide.html).

My program reads payment logs from file (on a HDFS cluster), transfers it to a dataframe and uses this dataframe in some sql queries. I ran my program in two cases: with and without cache() method. I encountered a weird problem as describe bellow:

1. Not using cache():

I tried to run some queries and everything was fine. (log_zw is my table name)

```
val num_records =  sqlContext.sql("select * from log_zw").count
val num_acc1 =  sqlContext.sql("select * from log_zw where ACN = 'acc1' ").count
```

2. Using cache()

I also used two queries above. The first query returned the correct value, but the second was **not**, it returned **0**.

However, when I queried it in another approach:

```
val num_acc1 = log_zw.filter(log_zw("ACN").contains("acc1")).count
```

it returned the correct result.

I'm very new to Spark and cluster computing system, I dont have any idea why it worked like that. Could anyone please explain to me this problem, especially the different when using sql query and spark method.

**Edit:** Here is the schema, it's very simple.

```
root 
 |-- PRODUCT_ID: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- CHANNEL: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- ACN: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- AMOUNT_VND: double (nullable = false) 
 |-- TRANS_ID: string (nullable = true)
```

**Edit2**: This is my code when using cache(): (I ran some queries and the results are showed in comments in code)

```
// read tsv files
case class LogZW(
  PRODUCT_ID: String,
  PLATFORM: String,
  CHANNEL: String,
  ACN: String,
  AMOUNT_VND: Double,
  TRANS_ID: String)

def loadLog(filename: String): DataFrame = {
  sc.textFile(filename).map(line => line.split("\t")).map(p =>
  LogZW(p(1), p(3), p(4), p(5), p(9).toDouble, p(10).substring(0,8))).toDF()
}

// generate schema
val schemaString = "PRODUCT_ID PLATFORM CHANNEL ACN AMOUNT_VND TRANS_ID"
val schema = StructType(schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))

// read all files
val HDFSFolder = "hdfs://master:54310/user/lqthang/data/*"
val log = loadLog(HDFSFolder)

// register table
log.registerTempTable("log")
log.show()

// select a subset of log table
val log_zw =  sqlContext.sql("select PRODUCT_ID, CHANNEL, ACN, AMOUNT_VND, TRANS_ID from log where PLATFORM = 'zingwallet' and CHANNEL not in ('CBZINGDEAL', 'VNPT') and PRODUCT_ID not in ('ZingCredit', 'zingcreditdbg') ")

// register new table
log_zw.show()
log_zw.registerTempTable("log_zw")

// cache table
log_zw.cache()

// this query returns incorrect value!!
val num_acc1 =  sqlContext.sql("select * from log_zw where ACN = 'acc1' ").count

// this query returns correct value!
val num_acc2 =  sqlContext.sql("select * from log_zw where trim(ACN) = 'acc1' ").count

// uncache data and try another query
log_zw.unpersist()

// this query also returns the correct value!!!
val num_acc2 =  sqlContext.sql("select * from log_zw where ACN = 'acc1' ").count
```

**Edit3**: I tried to add another cache() method to `log` dataframe:

```
// register table
log.registerTempTable("log")
log.show()
log.cache()
```

The following code is the same as above (with `log_zw.cache()`). So the important result is:

```
// this query returns the CORRECT value!!
val num_acc1 =  sqlContext.sql("select * from log_zw where ACN = 'acc1' ").count
```

Comment: Can you show us the schema?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto I added the schema.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a lot of details about what the data is, but I notice that your two code sections do different things.

In the first, you do `ACN = 'acc1'` but in the second you check if ACN **contains** 'acc1'.

So the second bit (with the filter) will match if ACN is ' acc1', or 'acc1 ', or 'acc1'

In other words, I bet if you add a trim to your SQL query you would get a different result.

So try this:

`val num_records =  sqlContext.sql("select * from log_zw").count
val num_acc1 =  sqlContext.sql("select * from log_zw where trim(ACN) = 'acc1' ").count`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Using **trim** gave me a correct result. However, it does not answer my question. Moreover, when not using **cache()** and **trim**: sqlContext.sql("select * from log_zw where ACN = 'acc1'").count also returns correct result.

Comment: I'd need more information.  Can you reduce to one sample that gives the incorrect count (you can change private info)?  That way we can try to reproduce this.  Where did you put the ``` cache()``` call? Please update your number 2 code (using cache).

Comment: As your suggestion, I have added the whole code and only showed one sample with the incorrect result.

Comment: I wanted to see an example of a LogZW instance that would fail so I could reproduce locally.

Try with this:
```val log_zw = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(LogZW("prodId", "zingwallet", "channel", "acc1 ", 75.0, "transid")))```

Replace the values in that LogZW with something that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem with only the failed instances, but it did not work. I think it is affected by the whole data set, so it's hard for you to reproduce it in local.

One more thing, I added another case in edit3.